# Grid View Selected row cell value getting null

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid in my asp.net page . Inside the selected index change event  I implemented the  below code .

```
 int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.Rows[selectedIndex +1].Cells[1].Text);
```

Cell1 is a  number,
 in the  Running time it gives me an error "Input string was not in a correct format" .It occurs due to "Text" is getting null in the running time. I  implemted  below code too in the Selected index changed event it always gets a value.

```
 int selectedIndex = grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedIndex;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `selectedIndex + 1`? This will give you the row below the selected row, and will throw an exception when the user selects the last row in the grid.

Try `int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.Rows[selectedIndex].Cells[1].Text);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this.. it is simple way to get data of selected row in gridview..
Try below code..

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
```

Comment: @user3383403, Hi, in my case Text is always null in all cells, note I have AutoGenerateColumns = false in my grid

Answer (score 1):

If u want selected value then u can set by `DataKeyName` and call on `SelectedIndexChanged` event..

```
string data = grdMnaualEntryTransactionTemplate.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the action buttons on the Grid, ie. Select, Edit etc, then these will be in the `Rows.Cells[]` array. Therefore if you have the three "Select" "Edit" "Delete" buttons per row, your first actual data cell will be array index[3].

As others have pointed out index+1 is incorrect as well.